# Update Firestore values when App is minimised/closed

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Trying to find which one of [these Background Processing methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5hE7.png) suits my case.

Case: **How can I update fields on Firestore when application is running on the background or when it's closed?**

Short Description: User inputs time (milliseconds) and when that time is over I want to update the fields in Firestore no matter if the app is running or closed, I currently have this code:

```
 private void setTaskEndTime(long xEndTime) {
        long mLeftTime = xEndTime - mCurrentTime;

        new CountDownTimer(mLeftTime, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //HERE <===================

            }
        }.start();

    }
```

*I have tried Firebase Cloud Function; so that when the time is over it was supposed to update the fields but the problem is the Cloud Function takes too much time before updating the fields (or at least my code):*

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
let db = admin.firestore();

exports.wtf = functions.region('europe-west1').firestore
    .document('Users/{userId}/Tasks/{docId}')
    .onUpdate((docSnapshot, context) => {
        var mUserID = context.params.userId;  //Document userID
        var mDocID = context.params.docId;    //Document taskID

        var oldSnapshot = docSnapshot.before.data();
        var oldCurrentStatus = oldSnapshot.taskCurrentStatus;
        var newSnapshot = docSnapshot.after.data();
        var newCurrentStatus = newSnapshot.taskCurrentStatus;

        var tempTime = newSnapshot.temporaryTime;

        let cityRef = db.collection('Users').doc(mUserID).collection('Tasks').doc(mDocID);

        if (newCurrentStatus !== oldCurrentStatus && newCurrentStatus > 0) {


            const myFunc = () => {
                //Gets dd/MM/yyyy date and stores it in 'today'
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

                let days = cityRef.update({
                    taskCompletedDays: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(today)
                });
                let hours = cityRef.update({
                    taskCompletedHours: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(tempTime)
                });
                let status = cityRef.update({ taskCurrentStatus: 0 });
            }

            setTimeout(myFunc, tempTime);

        }
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Code scheduled with `setTimeout` is not guaranteed to execute correctly in Cloud Functions.  A background Cloud Function (including Firestore triggers) [must return a promise that resolves when all of the asynchronous work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  After that, any pending work might get canceled or simply not execute correctly.  In short, don't depend on `setTimeout` unless you're 1) willing to return a promise that resolves only after the work is complete, and 2) never going to exceed the maximum configurable 9 minute timeout for Cloud Functions.

What you should do instead is use Google Cloud Tasks to schedule a future invocation of another (HTTP) function after some elapsed amount of time has expired.  You can read a detailed description in [this blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

Comment: I've looked into the blog and the documentation little bit, even though I think it's little overkill for my simple novice project I will try to implement and update this topic accordingly (it'll definitely take time because all these terms sound too complicated). Appreciate the help!

Comment: Since setTimeout won't work, this is actually the least complicated way to do this correctly, if you need to schedule the work precisely.